# Want cumulative sum by raw & column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

Below is my actual Data.

```
select Year,fall_unit,summer_unit,spring_unit
from (
select 2010 as Year,4 fall_unit,5 summer_unit,6 spring_unit
union
select 2011 as Year,7 fall_unit,23 summer_unit,90 spring_unit
union
select 2012 as Year,3 fall_unit,2 summer_unit,5 spring_unit) M
```

Wanted to do cumulative sum by raw & column also.

Required Output as per below.

```
2010    4     9   15
2011    22   45  135
2012  138   140  145
```

Below is the more explaination of calculation.

```
2010 : 9  = (4+5)
2010 : 15 = (9+6)
2011 : 22 = (15+7)
2011 : 45 = (22+23)
2011 : 135= (45+90) 
2012 : 138= (135+3)
2012 : 140= (138+2)
2012 : 145= (140+5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the updated query (last query). The output logic in my understanding is: 
Year | C1: Fall + previous_year_total | C2: Fall + summer + previous count | C3: TOTAL

```
create table #test(Year int, fall_unit int, summer_unit int, spring_unit int)

insert #test (Year, fall_unit, summer_unit, spring_unit)
select 2010 as Year,4 fall_unit,5 summer_unit,6 spring_unit
union
select 2011 as Year,7 fall_unit,23 summer_unit,90 spring_unit
union
select 2012 as Year,3 fall_unit,2 summer_unit,5 spring_unit

-- select * from #test

select t2.Year,
    case when t1.fall_unit IS NULL then t2.fall_unit
        else SUM(t1.rowTotal) OVER (ORDER BY t1.YEAR) + t2.fall_unit
    end as C1,
    case when t1.summer_unit IS NULL then t2.summer_unit + coalesce(t1.rowTotal, 0) + t2.fall_unit
        else SUM(t1.rowTotal) OVER (ORDER BY t1.YEAR) + t2.fall_unit + t2.summer_unit 
    end as C2,
    SUM(t2.rowTotal) OVER (ORDER BY t1.YEAR) as C3
from (select t.*, t.fall_unit + t.summer_unit + t.spring_unit as rowTotal from #test t) t1
right join (select t.*, t.fall_unit + t.summer_unit + t.spring_unit as rowTotal from #test t) t2 
on t1.YEAR+1 = t2.YEAR
order by t2.Year
```

Comment: It provide only grand total, I want the cumulative total as per describe in Required Output.

Comment: @Sandip, I updated the answer (query) to retrieve the required output.